# How to compile Tkinter as an executable for MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2app

I'm trying to compile a Tkinter app as an executable for MacOs. I tried to use `py2app` and `pyinstaller`. I almost succeed using `py2app`, but it returns the following error:

Traceback

```bash
The Info.plist file must have a PyRuntimeLocations array containing string values for preferred Python runtime locations.  
These strings should be "otool -L" style mach ids; "@executable_stub" and "~" prefixes will be translated accordingly.
```

This is how the `setup.py` looks like:

```py
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = ['config.json']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And this is the directory structure:

```
-modules/---__init.py__
|        | 
|        -- gui_module.py
|        |
|        -- scraper_module.py
|        |
|        -- app.ico
|
-config.json
|
-countries_list.txt
|
-main.py
|
-requirements.txt
|
-setup.py
```

I'm happy to share more details and the files if you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you need to give an executable path for the python framework you have on your MacOs. So I modify the `setup.py`

#### setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

class CONFIG:
    VERSION = 'v1.0.1'
    platform = 'darwin-x86_64'
    executable_stub = '/opt/homebrew/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' # this is important, check where is your Python framework and get the `dylib`
    APP_NAME = f'your_app_{VERSION}_{platform}'
    APP = ['main.py']
    DATA_FILES = [
        'config.json', 
        'countries_list.txt', 
        ('modules', ['modules/app.ico']),
        # this modules are automatically added if you use __init__.py in your folder
        # ('modules', ['modules/scraper_module.py']),
        # ('modules', ['modules/gui_module.py']),
    ]

    OPTIONS = {
        'argv_emulation': False,
        'iconfile': 'modules/app.ico',
        'plist': {
            'CFBundleName': APP_NAME,
            'CFBundleDisplayName': APP_NAME,
            'CFBundleGetInfoString': APP_NAME,
            'CFBundleVersion': VERSION,
            'CFBundleShortVersionString': VERSION,
            'PyRuntimeLocations': [
                executable_stub,
                # also the executable can look like this:
                #'@executable_path/../Frameworks/libpython3.4m.dylib',
            ]
        }
    }

def main():
    setup(
        name=CONFIG.APP_NAME,
        app=CONFIG.APP,
        data_files=CONFIG.DATA_FILES,
        options={'py2app': CONFIG.OPTIONS},
        setup_requires=['py2app'],
        maintainer='foo bar',
        author_email='foo@domain.com',
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then you need to run `python3 setup.py py2app` and now you can go and just double click on `your_app_{VERSION}_{platform}.app`.

#### Recomendations by the `py2app` docs:

1. Make sure not to use the -A flag
2. Do not use `--argv-emulation` when the program uses a GUI toolkit (as Tkinter) [py2app options docs](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html)

Comment: Would be awesome if you could update this answer. I'm having a problem with dylib with this config still. Can't find any reference to the kvp you set either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped a lot. Please, I was wondering if to compile a tkinter code to Mac app, it has to be done on a Mac computer, or it can be done on a Windows one as well?